# Change content on button click with vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that is dynamically generated from a JS file. I am mapping buttons from this array for each object. I want to:

1. Not seeing all objects when loading page but only one, let's say first element by default
2. Retrieve content according to clicked button and display it, and only this one

I could retrieve clicked button id but couldn't succeed in going further, any help would be welcome.

Here are my files:

index.js

```
    const menu = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "buttermilk pancakes",
        category: "breakfast",
        price: 15.99,
        img: "./images/item-1.jpeg",
        desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "diner double",
        category: "lunch",
        price: 13.99,
        img: "./images/item-2.jpeg",
        desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "godzilla milkshake",
        category: "shakes",
        price: 6.99,
        img: "./images/item-3.jpeg",
        desc: `ombucha chillwave fanny pack 3 wolf moon street art photo booth before they sold out organic viral.`,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: "country delight",
        category: "breakfast",
        price: 20.99,
        img: "./images/item-4.jpeg",
        desc: `Shabby chic keffiyeh neutra snackwave pork belly shoreditch. Prism austin mlkshk truffaut, `,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: "egg attack",
        category: "lunch",
        price: 22.99,
        img: "./images/item-5.jpeg",
        desc: `franzen vegan pabst bicycle rights kickstarter pinterest meditation farm-to-table 90's pop-up `,
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: "oreo dream",
        category: "shakes",
        price: 18.99,
        img: "./images/item-6.jpeg",
        desc: `Portland chicharrones ethical edison bulb, palo santo craft beer chia heirloom iPhone everyday`,
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        title: "bacon overflow",
        category: "breakfast",
        price: 8.99,
        img: "./images/item-7.jpeg",
        desc: `carry jianbing normcore freegan. Viral single-origin coffee live-edge, pork belly cloud bread iceland put a bird `,
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: "american classic",
        category: "lunch",
        price: 12.99,
        img: "./images/item-8.jpeg",
        desc: `on it tumblr kickstarter thundercats migas everyday carry squid palo santo leggings. Food truck truffaut  `,
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: "quarantine buddy",
        category: "shakes",
        price: 16.99,
        img: "./images/item-9.jpeg",
        desc: `skateboard fam synth authentic semiotics. Live-edge lyft af, edison bulb yuccie crucifix microdosing.`,
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        title: "steak dinner",
        category: "dinner",
        price: 39.99,
        img: "./images/item-10.jpeg",
        desc: `skateboard fam synth authentic semiotics. Live-edge lyft af, edison bulb yuccie crucifix microdosing.`,
      },
    ];
    
    const sectionCenter = document.querySelector(".section-center");
    const container = document.querySelector(".btn-container");
    
    // const {id, title, category, price, img, desc} = menu
    
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      displayMenuItems(menu);
      displayMenuButtons();
    });
    
    function displayMenuItems(menuItems) {
      let displayMenu = menuItems.map(function (item) {
        // console.log(item);
    
        return `<article class="menu-item">
              <img src=${item.img} class="photo" alt=${item.title} />
              <div class="item-info">
                <header>
                  <h4>${item.title}</h4>
                  <h4 class="price">$${item.price}</h4>
                </header>
                <p class="item-text">
                  ${item.desc}
                </p>
              </div>
            </article>`;
      });
      displayMenu = displayMenu.join("");
    
      sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu;
    }
    
    function displayMenuButtons(){
      const btns = menu.map(function(menuItem){
        // console.log(menuItem)
        return `<button class="filter-btn" type="button" data-id=${menuItem.id}>${menuItem.title}</button>`;
      })
      .join("");
      container.innerHTML = btns;
      
      const filterBtns = container.querySelectorAll(".filter-btn");
    
      filterBtns.forEach(function(btn){
        btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
          const categoryId = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
          console.log(categoryId)
          const menuCategory = menu.filter(function(menuItem, index){
            // console.log(menuItem)
            console.log(index)
            if(menuItem.id === categoryId){
              return menuItem;
            }
          })
          displayMenuItems(menuCategory)
        })
      })
    
    }
```

index.html

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="crew">
            <div class="btn-container"></div>
            <div class="section-center"></div>
        </section>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>```
````

Comment: You will have to look into something called AJAX in order to dynamically change content in vanilla JS. Essentially, you want to create a file that is built up on post parameters that you want to show (category etc. etc.). Once you have done that, you make an API call with that AJAX functionality, parsing a new, relevant set of parameters, making the content change. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To only see the first item of the list and without changing the `displaymenuitems()` function you could do the same as you did for detecting the button press.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  displayMenuItems(menu.filter(function(menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.id == 1) {
      return menuItem;
    }
  }));
  displayMenuButtons();
});
```

2. In order to make the buttons work you need to swap `===` to `==` as they are the same value but not the same type. [Read more about operators](https://codeahoy.com/javascript/2019/10/12/==-vs-===-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20between%20%3D%3D%20and%20%3D%3D%3D%20is%20that%3A,the%20two%20variables%20being%20compared.)

```js
if(menuItem.id == categoryId){
  return menuItem;
}
```

I made a JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o7de1b52/1/